# Use string methods in ES 5

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to use some string methods in ECMA 5 like:

```
->padStart();
->getHours();(different time formats)
```

I'm trying to use the string methods to extract just the time and the hours separately but it is throwing a type error.

```
var date = parseInt(reverseString(hexPayload.substring(0,8)),16).toString(10);
result.DateAndTime = new Date(date);
result.Volume1 = volume(reverseString(hexPayload.substring(18,26))) + 'meterCube' + date.getHours();
```

I can get the required output in browser javascript. But cannot use it an otto javascript engine based on ES 5. Can anyone suggest me how it is done or alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: `padStart` is not in ES5. And are you sure the `.getHours` throws the error?

Comment: @VLAZ. Yes it is. I'm using recent version of node.js and its throwing error. This is my second post on the same issue. If anyone knows how to achieve this in ES 5 would be great.

Answer (score 0):

About `getHours` it is not `String.prototype` method, it is `Date.prototype` method. And it is of the oldest methods in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours#Browser_compatibility. So your engine has to support. If not let us about the engine you are working with.

In you code

```
var date = parseInt(reverseString(hexPayload.substring(0,8)),16).toString(10);
result.DateAndTime = new Date(date);
result.Volume1 = volume(reverseString(hexPayload.substring(18,26))) + 'meterCube' + date.getHours();
```

In `date.getHours()` the `date` is *Number* not *Date*. Probably that is why you have error.

About `padStart`, there are polyfills you can use them, or copy. But needs to be set ahead of using it. For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Polyfill

Comment: What do you mean by setting ahead of using it. I have used polyfill as well but did not work. I copied it in-front of my code. Is it correct?

Comment: I'm using a middleware which uses otto javascript engine. It is based on ES 5.

Comment: Yes you need to copy and paste before using it. Strange if it does not work. Can you share your code? And it is ok if it has other languages, I suppose you are using Go.

Comment: Here is the link  [https://js.do/code/tbb]  to the code I have written. I'm also working in GO. But the code I'm writing is still in javascript.